# How to calculate the values that i got from a txt file?

Tags: java, arrays

so im trying to read the values that i got from my results.txt file and calculate them based on the CGPA format but seems like the method im trying is not working . I wonder if anyone can help me with this it is for my assignment for client server. The calculation part is under the View() method. PS sorry if my code is too hard to read and im still new to using java and this is my first time posting here

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class MultiClientHandler1 extends Thread {
  private Socket client;
  private BufferedReader in, in2,in3;
  private PrintWriter out, out2;
  private String received, data,result;
  private String array[], array2[], array3[],array4[];
  private int found=0;

  public MultiClientHandler1(Socket socket) {
    client = socket;
    try {
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
      out2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("students.txt", true));
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void Register() {
    String reply="";
    array = received.split(":");

    if(array[1].length() != 7)
      reply = "Err1";
    else if(array[2].length() < 5)
      reply = "Err2";
    else if(array[3].length() < 5)
      reply = "Err3";
    else {
      reply= "+OK";
      out2.println(array[1]+":"+array[2]+":"+array[3]);
      out2.close();
    }
    out.println(reply);
  }

  public void login() throws IOException {
    in2 = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader("students.txt"));
    while((data = in2.readLine()) != null) {
      array3=data.split(":");
      if((array2[1].equals(array3[0])) && (array2[2].equals(array3[1]))) {
        out.println("Login successfully");
        found=1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(found==0)
      out.println("Login Error");
  }

  public void View() throws IOException {
    String grade = "", cgpa = "";
    int IntValue = 0, IntCH = 0, IntCGPA = 0, IntArray = 0;
    in3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("results.txt"));
    while((result = in3.readLine()) != null) {
      array4=result.split(":");
      if((array2[1].equals(array4[0])) && (array2[2].equals(array4[1]))) {
        grade += array4[2] + " " + array4[3] + " " + array4[4] + "...........";
        found = 1;
        if(array4[3] == "A") {
          IntArray = Integer.parseInt(array4[3]);
          IntValue = IntArray * 4;
        } else if(array4[3] == "B") {
          IntArray = Integer.parseInt(array4[3]);
          IntValue = IntArray * 3;
        }
        IntCH += IntArray;
        IntCGPA = IntValue/IntCH;
        out.println(IntCGPA);
      }
      if(found==0)
        out.println("No Records");
    }
    out.println(grade);
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      do {
        found=0;
        received = in.readLine();
        array2=received.split(":");
        if (received.equals("QUIT")) break;

        switch(received.charAt(0)) {
          case 'R':
            Register();
            break;
          case 'L':
            login();
            break;
          case 'V':
            View();
            break;
        }
      } while (!received.equals("QUIT"));
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if(client != null) {
          System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
          client.close();
        }
      } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
    these are the content in the results.txt file
    0118210:1801:XDCS1094:A:4
    0118210:1801:XDCS2034:B+:4
    0118210:1801:XDCS1043:C:3
    0118024:1801:XDCS1094:B:4
    0118024:1801:XDCS2094:A:4
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: when i try to run the program and type V:018210:1801 it should display my results that are from the results.txt file and calculate the CGPA based on the results but instead it shows null